# Pöschl–Teller free wave solution normalization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

I'm considering one-dimentional QM ($\hbar=1$, $m=1$) with the following potential
$$
V(x) = - \frac{1}{\cosh^2 x}\;.
$$
I know that free-wave solution are
$$
ψ_k(x) = e^{\pm i k x}(\tanh x \mp ik)\;.
$$
I expect these solution to be $δ$-normalized, that is
$$
∫\mathrm{d}x\, ψ^*_{k'}(x)ψ_k(x) = δ(k-k')\;,
$$
however it is not clear to me how to prove this result. Explicitly, choosing  the upper sign, I have
$$
∫\mathrm{d}x\; e^{i(k-k')x}\,(\tanh x + ik')(\tanh x - ik) \,,
$$
which, exploiting the fact that $\tanh$ is odd reduces to
$$
∫\mathrm{d}x\, e^{i(k-k')x}(\tanh^2 x + k'k ) \;.
$$
Of course I have to use a test function
$$
∫\mathrm{d}x\, e^{i(k-k')x}(\tanh^2 x + k'k )φ(k) = ∫\mathrm{d}x\,[(k'k + \tanh^2 (-i∂_k))e^{i(k-k')x}]φ(k) \;,
$$
integrating by parts one hase
$$
∫\mathrm{d}x\,e^{i(k-k')x}[(k'k+\tanh^2 (-i∂_k))φ(k)] = δ(k-k')[(k'k+\tanh^2 (-i∂_k))φ(k)] \;,
$$
which does not seem to be the correct answer, due to the presence of that $\tanh^2 (-i∂_k)$.

### Question

What is the way out?

Answer (score 2):

Since these are solutions to a Hermitian eigenvalue equation, you know they are orthogonal (except possibly for the $k$,$-k$ pair which is degenerate but it is easy to see this pair is orthogonal). So it has delta function normalization, you only need to determine the overall normalization coefficient. Taking the limit that $k'$ is very near $k$, so that $|k'-k| \ll 1$ you can set the $\tanh(x)^2$ in your integral to unity since the part of the integral where it is not unity is negligible. You get
$\int dx~ e^{i(k-k')x}(\tanh^2x+kk')\rightarrow \int dx ~e^{i(k-k')x} (1+kk')$. This is a standard Fourier integral and gives
\begin{equation}
\int dx~ \psi_k(x)^*\psi_k(x) = 2\pi (1+k^2)\delta(k-k')\,.
\end{equation}

Comment: How can you say that only the part where $\tanh^2$ is not near unity is negligible?

Comment: I know that $\delta$ normalization was expected. I was wondering however how can one rederive it from scratch, i.e. if one is given just the normalization integral without knowing its origin, how can one argue the result?

Comment: My first sentence uses the proof that eigenstates of a Hermitian operator with different eigenvalues are orthogonal. It does not assume there is a delta function normalization. You know then for $k \neq k'$ the integral is zero. The $1-\tanh^2(x)$ is negligible because for $k=k'$ its integral is finite (2 I think) compared to the integral of 1 which goes to infinity. For arbitrary integrals that you know nothing about, the integration is obviously harder.

Comment: I understand that you used spectral theorem. I would like to know the "harder" proof, just as a mathematical curiosity